# Laravel whereHas behaving unexpectedly

Tags: laravel, eloquent, query-builder

I have the following relationships set up in my Laravel 5.6 application.

`Purchase belongs to many Invoice`

`Invoice belongs to many Purchase`

`Invoice belongs to many Payment`

`Payment belongs to many Invoice`

These relationships are made using pivot tables.

I want to find **only** purchases that have, via invoices, payments that are 0.

In my test I have **one** purchase, I have attached **two** invoices to that purchase, and I have attached **one** payment to each of those invoices. One payment has the amount 100, the other has the amount 0.

For my test to pass, the query should return no results, however, it isn't doing so, it is consistently returning the purchase I have created.

This is the query i've written:

```
Purchase::whereHas('invoices.payments', function ($q) {
   return $q->where('amount', '<=', 0);
})->get();
```

I have also tried:

```
Purchase::whereDoesntHave('invoices.payments', function ($q) {
   return $q->where('amount', '>', 0);
})->get();
```

Am I doing something wrong here? Am I misunderstanding the capabilities of WhereHas?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: >I want to find only purchases that have, via invoices, payments that are 0. >One payment has the amount 100, the other has the amount 0. >it is consistently returning the purchase I have created. Looks right?

Comment: Do you want to take result that ONLY have payment with zero amount without payments with amount > 0?

Comment: I want Purchases, that through invoices, ONLY have payments of 0. If that purchase has ANY payments related to it with amounts over 0, I don't want the purchase.

Comment: Second query looks right. Could you share `dd(Purchase::whereDoesntHave('invoices.payments', function ($q) {
   return $q->where('amount', '>', 0);
})->toSql())`

Comment: Sure, thanks for the help: ```select * from `purchases` where exists (select * from `invoices` inner join `invoice_purchase` on `invoices`.`id` = `invoice_purchase`.`invoice_id` where `purchases`.`id` = `invoice_purchase`.`purchase_id` and not exists (select * from `payments` inner join `invoice_payment` on `payments`.`id` = `invoice_payment`.`payment_id` where `invoices`.`id` = `invoice_payment`.`invoice_id` and `amount` > ? and `payments`.`deleted_at` is null) and `invoices`.`deleted_at` is null) and `purchases`.`deleted_at` is null```

Comment: I added the answer. Please check, and give a feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second approach is correct, but `whereDoesntHave()` doesn't work properly with nested relationships in Laravel 5.6. This bug has been [fixed](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/26228) in Laravel 5.7.

You can use this workaround:

```php
Purchase::whereDoesntHave('invoices', function ($q) {
    $q->whereHas('payments', function ($q) {
        $q->where('amount', '>', 0);
    });
})->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, You should use both of methods.

```
Purchase::whereHas('invoices.payments', function ($q) {
        return $q->where('amount', 0);
    })
    ->whereDoesntHave('invoices.payments', function ($q) {
        return $q->where('amount', '>', 0);
    })
    ->get();
```

`whereHas()` take all purchases with payment amount = 0, `whereDoesntHave()` throw away purchases that have payments > 0.

Comment: Sadly still no luck with that. Thanks @IndianCoding. I'm beginning to doubt my test setup, although I've been over it countless times.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps its me not fully understanding your requirements / the problem here but this is what I think I understand...

You created 1 `Purchase`.
It has 2 `Invoice`s.
Each `Invoice` has 1 `Payment` (1 of 100, 1 of 0 <- technically not a payment).

In your question you say

> I want to find **only** purchases that have, via invoices, payments that
>   are 0.

But then you are complaining that you got a result...  When you **DO** have a purchase with a zero payment.

To make the test a bit more "real", I would create many `Purchase`s with many `Invoice`s and `Payment`s etc to really get a feel for whats going on.

**UPDATE**

Have you considered a 'hasManyThrough' relationship on your Purchase model to the Payment?  like this

```
public function payment()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Payment::class, Invoice::class);
}
```

Then perhaps you could do this query.

```
Purchase::whereDoesntHave('payment')->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer John, you're right, I do only want the purchases that have related payments of the amount 0. But, if that payment also has a related payment above 0 I don't want it. For clarity in the description I mentioned that I'm only using one purchase, but in reality my test, like you suggested, uses many purchases. I get the same behaviour with many as with one.

Comment: I have made an update to my answer.  Not sure if that'll help?